# 401 API Authentication Failed using POST Method

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, post, xmlhttprequest

I am implementing an API which is based on POST method. Now, I have tried axios as well as fetch (promise) method but I am constantly having this error of "401 Authentication Failed".

- For testing, I defined the data values to be sent into this.state as default values.
- **apiKey** and **userId** are defined as var outside the React.Component.
- Instead of using inbuilt **btoa** function, I am using the one from npm directory which is imported on the top.

Here is the React Component code:-

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      day: 1,
      month: 2,
      year: 2019,
      hours: 12,
      minutes: 59,
      tzone: 5.5,
      lat: 19.22,
      lon: 25.2
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {

      const options = {
      headers: {
        "Authorization": "Basic" + btoa(userId+":"+apiKey),
        "Content-Type":'application/json'
      }
    };

      const url = `https://json.astrologyapi.com/v1/current_vdasha`
      const data = this.state

      fetch(url, { method: 'POST', 
        body: JSON.stringify(data), 
        headers: options })
        .then(res => res.json())
        .catch(error => console.error('error ---', error.message))
        .then(response => console.log('Success:', response));
  }
```

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: We  need to see the api code to understand why this fails.

Comment: @AthanasiosKataras What exactly should I provide you with? Here is what the API devs provide for reference -- ```var userId = '';
var apiKey = '';
var data = 'JSON Request Data';
var request = $.ajax({
url: "https://json.astrologyapi.com/v1/"+api,
method: "POST",
dataType:'json',
headers: {
"authorization": "Basic " + btoa(userId+":"+apiKey),
"Content-Type":'application/json'
},
data:JSON.stringify(data)
});
// Returns A promiss
return( request.then( function(resp){
return resp;
}, function(err){
return err;
}));
}```

Answer (score 2):

In the header part of the request try adding space after "Basic" which should look like this :
'''

```
const options = {
headers: {
    "Authorization": "Basic " + btoa(userId+":"+apiKey),
    "Content-Type":'application/json'
  }
};
```

'''
As the authentication header first expects the type of authorization followed by space and then the api key

Comment: I checked that out before also but it doesn't seem to fix the error.

Answer (score 0):

When you pass headers to the fetch function, you pass it inside another object.

In the fetch function, try to change `headers: options` to `headers: options.headers`.

Comment: It seems like this was part of the fix but it produces 405 Method not allowed error.

Comment: POST https://json.astrologyapi.com/v1/current_vdasha 405 (Method Not Allowed)